# Computing Gauss Legendre quadrature for large $N$

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, integration, orthogonal-polynomials, quadrature, legendre-polynomials

I've been scanning across the web, and haven't found a good method to compute the Gauss Legendre abscissas and weights $\{ x_j, w^j \} _{j=1}^N$ for large $N\in\mathbb{N}$. My question is how to do it, and why should it work?

*To those who need some background:*

The goal is to approximate an integral by a discrete interpolating sum:

$$\int\limits_{(-1,1)} f(x) dx = \sum\limits_{j=-N}^N f(x_j)w^j $$

The question is, how to choose  $\{ x_j, w^j \} _j$ appropriately.The Gauss Legendre quadrature tells you (for good reasons) to choose $x_j $ to be the roots of the $n$-th Legendre polynomial.

**Problem** : A straightforward computation of the Legendre polynomial for high $N$ is highly unstable, as it involves "big" coefficients of alternating signs.

**EDIT**: 
I've found a very simple code that computes weight and abscissas using eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix, but doesn't seem use Golub Welsch. The matrix is

$$\forall 1\leq j\leq N-1 \,  A_{j,j+1} = A_{j+1,j}  = \frac{j}{\sqrt{4j^2 -1}}$$ with all other entries are zero. The discussion about it was [split to another post.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236087/symmetric-matrix-formula-for-gaus-legendre-quadrature)

Comment: I know I already got some answers, but I'm really intrigued whether or not anyone understands the solution I've quoted in the "edit" section

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are asymptotic methods that essentially give you $N$ nodes and weights in $O(N)$ time if the precision is assumed to be fixed (e.g. at double precision).

See Nicholas Hale and Alex Townsend, "Fast and Accurate Computation of Gauss-Legendre and Gauss-Jacobi Quadrature Nodes and Weights", SIAM J. Sci. Comput., 35(2) (a PDF is available at http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/1629/1/finalOR79.pdf, [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20181102000941/http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/1629/1/finalOR79.pdf)).

They claim that their algorithm achieves double precision accuracy for $N \ge 100$.

For $N < 100$, you may as well precompute a big table with perfect accuracy using a computer algebra system or arbitrary precision library of your choice (or look up tables that others have published).

As to computing Legendre polynomials in a numerically stable way, use the three-term recurrence $(n+1) P_{n+1}(x) = (2n+1) x P_n(x) - n P_{n-1}(x)$ to evaluate $P(x)$ directly instead of computing the coefficients of the polynomial and using Horner's rule (similarly for $P'(x)$).

**Update (2019)**: the issue of efficient computation for large N *with arbitrary precision* (and also with rigorous error bounds) is addressed in new work by myself and Marc Mezzarobba: SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing, 2018, Vol. 40, No. 6 : pp. C726-C747
https://doi.org/10.1137/18M1170133 (https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03948).

Answer (score 7):

To add to Fredrik Johansson's answer: A nice history of algorithms for computing Gauss quadrature rules can be found in [this SIAM News article by Alex Townsend](https://sinews.siam.org/Details-Page/the-race-to-compute-high-order-gausslegendre-quadrature-1).  Therein, it is stated that the "final chapter" was written by Ignace Bogaert in [this SISC paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/140954969), which gives an algorithm that is even faster and more accurate than the algorithm of Hale & Townsend.

There is a free open-source implementation at https://sourceforge.net/projects/fastgausslegendrequadrature/

Comment: In addition to the C++ implementation of Bogaert's algorithm mentioned above, C versions can be found at  https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/fastgl/fastgl.html or at https://github.com/jjgreen/fastglc